# Round to n decimal places

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In Objective-C, how do you round a number to *n* decimal places, when *n* is a variable (i.e. I cannot use something like `%.2f`). The rounding should be as follows (if *n* equals 2):

- 12.224 --> 12.22
- 12.225 --> 12.23
- 12.3 --> 12.30
- -12.225 --> -12.23

NB: Using the (if *n* is 2) multiplied by 100, rounded, divided by 100 is not an option, as *n* could be quite high, and there would be a small error with high values of *n*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use asterisk to pass `n` to formatting functions at runtime:

```
NSString *formatted1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f", 2, 12.224];
// Produces @"12.22"
NSString *formatted2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f", 2, 12.225];
// Produces @"12.23"
```

Comment: +1 for asterisk. I never knew you could do this, awesome.